# How to get the value of state from redux when the component is opened in anothe browser tab?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Currently I'm trying to implement the redux toolkit in my application and there i have created the store and set the value to the state.

But the issue is I'm unable to access the value stored in the redux state wen I open the component in new tab. So how it can be done please suggest.

Here is the code for the reference:-

**intex.tsx**

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';
import './styles/css/index.css';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './util/redux/store';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container!);

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
);

module.hot?.accept();
```

**gridRowSlice.tsx**

```
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState } from './store';

export interface GridState {
  activeRow: any;
}

const initialState: GridState = {
  activeRow: {},
};

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'gridRow',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    move: (state, action) => {
      state.activeRow = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { move } = dataSlice.actions;

export const movedData = (state: RootState) => state.stocksList.activeRow;
export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

**hooks.tsx**

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

**store.tsx**

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import gridRowReducer from './gridRowSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    stocksList: gridRowReducer,
  },
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, RootState, unknown, Action<string>>;
```

In this component I have used dispatch to send some data from the table.

```
import { move } from '../../util/redux/gridRowSlice';
import { useAppDispatch } from '../../util/redux/hooks';

const table = () => {

useEffect(() => { 
dispatch(move(tableData)); 
});

  return (
      <div>
        //code for table
      </div>
  );
};
export default table;
```

And in other component I want to access the value of updated state and I tried different approach but non is working for me.
This is what I have tried.

```
import { store } from '../util/redux/store';
import { useAppSelector } from '../util/redux/hooks';


const receiveData = () => {
const data = useAppSelector(movedData);
const view = store.getState();
const view2 = useAppSelector((state) => state.stocksList.activeRow);

useEffect(() => { 
console.log(store.getState(), 'data1'); //returning blank object
console.log(data, 'data2'); //returning blank object
console.log(view, 'data3'); //returning blank object
console.log(view2, 'data4');  //returning blank object
    });
  return (
      <div>
        //code
      </div>
  );
};
export default receiveData;
```

**Note:- I want to get the value of state in another tab also when its opened while the application is running.**

Comment: Can you see in the Redux Devtools if the store has the value you are expecting it to have?

Comment: Can you try it with hot module reloading turned off?

Comment: @phry Yes in Redux Devtools the store has the value which I'm expecting

Comment: @JakubKotrs Yes I have tried it with keeping hot module reloading turned off but it's still not working.

Comment: What is `useAppSelector`? Could you share the code for that?

Comment: Have you tried a basic `useSelector(state => state)` in your component to see if that works?

Comment: @cdimitroulas Yes I have tried it but that is also not working

Comment: @cdimitroulas Please have a look at hook.tsx it is there in the above code.

Comment: And where/how are you rendering your `receiveData` component?

Answer (score 1):

The data stored in the Redux Store is typically a Global JS Object.

You cannot access a variable that is declared in a tab from another, until we persist it somewhere. Eg. Storing it in LocalStorage and syncing it via [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)

Simple solution should be using `redux-state-sync` to sync the data across multiple tabs.

If your application requires the data to be there even after reloading, you can persist it using `redux-persist`

Reference: https://github.com/aohua/redux-state-sync